# Using buses in multisheet

Tags: altium, bus

I'm using AD8283 which is a ADC IC and has 12 bits output.
In my design I'm using two pieces of it by using Repeat() command.
My question is how to connect data buses to next level.
I thought using Repeat() for [image]data buses might work but it didn't.

Comment: how is this related to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/309354/multi-output-in-multi-sheet-regulator-in-altium ? Feels like these two should be one question.

Comment: @Marcus Müller These are different problems I've faced in the same project. That one was problem with voltage supply and this is with ADC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat() currently doesn't support buses or harnesses in Altium.  Supposedly that feature is in development (https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Idea/2831).

Your best option at the moment is to place two of your ADC blocks on your main sheet (without using the repeat command).  You could also break out the bus into individual ports and still use the repeat command, but then you wind up with 12 buses with two nets each, which I wouldn't call an improvement.

As an aside, given the number of connections you need to make for each ADC, you may want to use harnesses to consolidate many signals into a single port.

Comment: As of 2021-08-23, via a case I opened with Altium support, I can confirm that `Repeat()` still does not support harnesses.